# PostgresSQL: Fill values for null rows based on rows for which we do have values

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table:

```
   country year rank
1  Austria 2019    1
2  Austria 2018   NA
3  Austria 2017   NA
4  Austria 2016   NA
5    Spain 2019    2
6    Spain 2018   NA
7    Spain 2017   NA
8    Spain 2016   NA
9  Belgium 2019    3
10 Belgium 2018   NA
11 Belgium 2017   NA
12 Belgium 2016   NA
```

I want to fill in the NA values for 2018, 2017 and 2016 for each country with the value for 2019 (which we have).
I want the output table to look like this:

```
   country year rank
1  Austria 2019    1
2  Austria 2018    1
3  Austria 2017    1
4  Austria 2016    1
5    Spain 2019    2
6    Spain 2018    2
7    Spain 2017    2
8    Spain 2016    2
9  Belgium 2019    3
10 Belgium 2018    3
11 Belgium 2017    3
12 Belgium 2016    3
```

I do not know where to get started with this question. I typically work with R but am now working on a platform which uses postgresSQL. I could do this in R but thought it would be worthwhile to figure out how it is done with postgres.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an update to join to find the non `NULL` rank value for each country:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable AS t1
SET "rank" = t2.max_rank
FROM
(
    SELECT country, MAX("rank") AS max_rank
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY country
) t2
WHERE t2.country = t1.country;
-- AND year IN (2016, 2017, 2018)
```

Add the commented out portion of the `WHERE` clause if you really only want to target certain years (your example seems to imply that you want to backfill all missing data).

If you just want to *view* your data in the format of the output, then use `MAX` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT country, year, MAX("rank") OVER (PARTITION BY country) AS "rank"
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY country, year DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the output then
try this,

```
with cte as (
select distinct on (country) * from test 
order by country, year desc
)
select 
t1.id,t1.country,t1.year,t2.rank 
from test t1 left join cte t2 on t1.country=t2.country
```

If you want to update your table then try this:

```
with cte as (
select distinct on (country) * from test 
order by country, year desc
)
update test set rank=cte.rank from cte
where test.country=cte.country
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1848c197e46365fdad66ac9c5eeb4f26)

Comment: I was looking to update my table. Thank you for your response, this worked!

Comment: Note that `RANK` is a reserved keyword, and you may need to escape it to get the above code to run.